# SVN Server - WebDAV

Tags: svn, webdav, box-api

I have a box.net account which supports webDAV & I'd like to use it as an svn server. I mounted the drive on my mac & then tried creating a repository using `svnadmin create /Volumes/dav` but this returned an error:

```
svnadmin: Repository creation failed
svnadmin: Creating pre-revprop-change hook
svnadmin: Can't open file '/Volumes/dav/FileShare/hooks/pre-revprop-change.tmpl': Interrupted system call
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cloud storage for storing SVN repositories in it - but the "SVN in DAV concept" will not work as A.H. already pointed out.

I use [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/) in combination with SVN repositories in the local file system. The repositories are automatically synced using the DropBox client with the cloud storage. This is of course only a suitable solution for single developers or teams in which write collisions can not happen as the SVN repository should not be used while incoming changes are replicated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that creating an SVN repository *inside* a WebDAV provider is either supported or a wise idea. Usually you have SVN repository which is *accessible* via WebDAV (i.e. SVN itself is the WebDAV provider). Both WebDAV and SVN have support for versioning, locking, submission etc. Cascading these things will be ... funny.